# IE 7 fun - Or why the submit button jumped

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

```
Let me spin you tale, of wondrous feats
And steal right from you now, your very speech
Entertain on the way, with my super mad beats
And ask for your help, as I claim defeat

An adventure was sought, so foolishly
Transforming my forms, so stylishly
I'd tinkered and toyed, and I knew the ways
To tame the great beast, and keep bugs at bay

Borders be gone, and colors deleted
Through to the page, everything bleeded
I'd conquered the layout, height and the width
With colors and size, everything fit
Stood on my prey, IE defeated
But lying in lurk, was something quite seeded

Upon form selection, a bug did occur
From the depths it did rise, nasty for sure
Borders sprang forth, they rise from the dead
A foe whom I'd thought, I'd put to bed
But taunt me they do, destroying my style
So back I did go, into my files
But naught did I find, oh not a trace
Though my fingers did fly, my heart keeping pace

I stand here defeated, unsure what to do
So I pulled out the case, made a demo for you
I come here for you, and feel like a dope
saying "Help me Obi-Wan Kenobi, you're my only hope"
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jkwFm/4/embedded/result/)

Open in IE 7 and select the search box. When the search box is selected, borders appear on the submit button. How do I fix the borders so they do not appear when the search box is selected?

Comment: please ask it as a real question, not a poem.

Comment: @DanielA.White Clarified my question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE7 highlights the button that would be activated if the user were to hit the Enter key.

There isn't anything that can be done about it, and it's the sort of thing that should only be applied to unstyled buttons, which is why it was removed/fixed in IE8.

Comment: Is there some way to counteract the effect?